# golden ratio splits too narrow when having a vertical split on a horizontal portion

Tags: spacemacs, window-splitting

When I have a split as such

```
+++++++++++
|         |
+++++++++++
|b   |c   |
|    |    |
+++++++++++
```

Focusing in the a column works as expected, but for this layout

```
+++++++++++++++++++
|         |       |
+++++++++++       |
|b      | |       |
|       | |       |
+++++++++++++++++++
```

focusing on b squishes the layout directly beside it, rather than evenly distributing between the one that takes up both rows.

Comment: So what is your question? Is "golden ratio" a special package?

Answer (score 1):

Golden Ratio is an emacs package. It's home page is at https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio.el

golden-ratio.el has a relatively large number of open issues (19) for such a small and specific package. Resizing windows dynamically is clearly not an exact nor easy art. Home page documents several variables you can set to try to adjust the workings of the package to your screen and frame size. Go through its open and closed issues to see if your problem has already been reported. If not, do open a new issue.

It might be best to make the emacs frame full screen and keep it like while you experiment with configuration.